# How to know the request came from a trigger click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons namely 'Reject button' and  'Prev button'. On click of the Reject button I am doing a trigger call to the Prev button. Is it possible to know inside the Prev button handler that a request came from by clicking on the Reject button?

This is my code

```js
$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(event) {
  var event_from = event.target.tagName;
  alert(event_from);
});

$(document).on('click', '#reje', function(event) {
  $("#prev").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="reje" value="Reject">
</div>
<input type="button" id="prev" value="prev">
```

I have tried by using the `event.target.tagName;` but I am getting value as `INPUT` in both the cases

http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/4350/

Comment: `event.target.id`? Or `$(this).attr('id');` or `$(this).val();` `tagName` is not going to work since they are both the same.

Comment: You want to get the event of the previous function? Is that correct?

Comment: because the event was triggered on the button you manually triggered the event on. You are not going to get the event of the original click. Inspecting the event objects, you would see what is different between the two.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. If you need to know that the event was triggered somewhere else, it's likely that you really meant to call a shared function rather than trigger the same handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to know inside the Prev button handler that a request came from by clicking on the Reject button?

One option is to check the `.isTrigger` property on the `event` object. It should return true if the event was triggered (like in this case). As pointed out in the comments below, this *is* an undocumented internal feature which [can potentially change](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/319) (although that is arguably unlikely at this point). See the other alternative options below.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/whLv70r1/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(event) {
  if (event.isTrigger) {
    alert('Triggered by reject.');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#reje', function(event) {
  $("#prev").click();
});
```

---

You could also check the `.originalEvent` property on the `event` object in order to determine how the event originated. The property is only set if the event [originated from the browser](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/319#issuecomment-19018756), which means that it will be `undefined` when triggered:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dnf6krv/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(event) {
  if (event.originalEvent === undefined) {
    alert('Triggered by reject.');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#reje', function(event) {
  $("#prev").click();
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could set a flag before triggering the click event:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/onb1jt7s/)

```
var triggeredByReject = false;

$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(event) {
  if (triggeredByReject) {
    triggeredByReject = false;
    alert('Triggered by reject.');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#reje', function(event) {
  triggeredByReject = true;
  $("#prev").click();
});
```

---

Another option would be to compare the timestamps on the events:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zz95bj1p/)

```
var lastRejectClick = 0;
$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(event) {
  if (lastRejectClick > event.timeStamp) {
    alert('Triggered by reject.');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#reje', function(event) {
  lastRejectClick = event.timeStamp + 10;
  $("#prev").click();
});
```

<sup>*I added 10 milliseconds to the timestamp to account for potential timestamp approximations/differences.</sup>

Comment: It appears you're taking advantage of an undocumented internal feature to jQuery. While I generally have no problem with using such features, it's worth at least calling out that it could break without warning if the implementation changes.

Comment: @zzzzBov You're right, surprisingly I couldn't find any official documentation on the property. Based on [the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d92310050ca7bf0b33825d64e052f9a8809c3e9e/test/data/jquery-1.9.1.js#L3026), it should always be true if the event was triggered, so I highly doubt that it will change. I agree with your comment above though, this seems like an XY problem. There are various other solutions.